# Can't find "User" class for Dropwizard Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, dropwizard

I'm trying to implement an authentication system in my Dropwizard application, but am unable to use the User class that all the examples I can find seem to take for granted.

I'm using the information from Dropwizard's own site, which matches various other tutorials and examples I've found online in how it implements an authenticator.

https://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/auth.html

This is the example Authenticator, which I have essentially copied:

```
 public class ExampleAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> {
     @Override
     public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
         if ("secret".equals(credentials.getPassword())) {
             return Optional.of(new User(credentials.getUsername()));
         }
         return Optional.absent();
     }
 }
```

However, when I try to do this, the only way my IDE can resolve the "User" dependency is as User from the "org.jetty.eclipse.Authentication" library, which fails to compile because it does not extend the Principal class required by the Authenticator interface.

This is the relevant portion of my pom:

```
 <properties>
    <dropwizard.version>1.3.5</dropwizard.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

The code either refuses to compile because the Jetty version of "User" doesn't fit the interface, or because it can't find any other version of "User".  Is there a dependency I'm missing?  Am I supposed to be implementing my own User class, and this just wasn't mentioned in any of the samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should supply your own implementation of the `Principle` interface class. Note the following sentence from the documentation and the second template parameter:

```
Authenticators implement the Authenticator<C, P extends Principal> interface, which has a single method:
```

There is the `dropwizard-example` project where this is demonstrated:

- https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/5c74a4894395303fad547b036859ab16535f101a/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/auth/ExampleAuthenticator.java#L3
- https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/5c74a4894395303fad547b036859ab16535f101a/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/core/User.java#L6